# ¿Cómo puedo poner una opción determinada en un DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Mi problema viene al querer realizar una modificación en un elemento de una tabla, salta una ventana modal con los datos, pero  al querer que el `DropDownListFor` se quede seleccionada la opción guardada en la base de datos, me muestra el primer valor por defecto.

Dejo a continuación el código con el que estoy probando:

Modelo:

```
 public class ArticuloVm
    {        
        public string Valor { get; set; }
        public List<ArticulosPropiedades> ListaPropiedades { get; set; }
        public List<ClaseArticulos> ListaClases { get; set; }
        public List<ClaseArticulos> ListaSubClases { get; set; }
        //Lista para obtener los datos a modificar
        public List<ModificarArticulos> Modificar { get; set; }
        public int? Id{ get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Clase { get; set; }
        public string CodigoEan { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    }


//Clase para asignar los datos desde la BD
public class ModificarArticulos
    {
        public int IdPropiedad { get; set; }
        public string Valor { get; set; }
        public int IdClase { get; set; }
        public int IdSubClase { get; set; }
    }
```

El `DropDownListFor` que estoy usando para generar la lista con el value seleccionado es:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modificar[0].IdClase, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase"), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px"})
```

Me sigue mostrando el primer valor de la lista en vez de mostrarme el que quiero que me muestre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viendo el [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sPDf59) en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211625/10053314) pregunta y realizando varias pruebas y búsquedas, vi que se podía incorporar un cuarto dato a mi `DropDownListFor` de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Modificar[0].IdClase, new SelectList(Model.ListaClases, "IdClase", "Clase", Model.Modificar[0].IdClase), new { @class = "input form-control input-lg", @required = "required", @style = "height: 40px; font-size:16px", })
```

Este cuarto elemento dentro del `SelectList` marca el resultado correcto dentro del DropDown